# Reusing Rails' param parsing to turn a one dimensional hash into a multideminonal one based on the key values and array notation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters, mechanicalturk

I am currently using [rturk](http://github.com/mdp/rturk) which give me back my answers in a one dimensional hash as such...

```
{"answers[125][rating]"=>"5", "answers[126][rating]"=>"5", "commit"=>"Take Survey", "answers[125][rating]"=>"5", "authenticity_token"=>"je0Hx48qKmCzy1zmXCpijYWbl4w92eDMRajWJcVYxe0=", "gender"=>"m", "answers[120][rating]"=>"5", "answers[121][rating]"=>"5", "income"=>"$75,000 to $100,000", "answers[122][rating]"=>"5", "date[year]"=>"1992", "career"=>"Marketer", "answers[123][rating]"=>"5", "answers[124][rating]"=>"5"}
```

What I would like to do is parse those into a multidimensional hash that I can then just pass as attributes.  If I can figure this out I'd probably switch from form_tag back to rails stand object forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query could help you, but you need to convert hash to string:

```
h = {"answers[125][rating]"=>"5", ...} # your hash
s = h.to_a.collect { |a| a.join('=') }.join('&')
Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query(s)
```

Comment: so I figured out rails added to_query to the Hash class so I don't even need that!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Turkee gem (http://github.com/aantix/turkee) as it will do this object mapping for you.